# Laravel. Указать таблицу для where

Tags: laravel

В контроллера выполняется запрос

```
Model::with('table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5')
->where('name', 'hello');
```

Проблема в том, что поле name присутствует во всех таблицах. Как указать нужную?

Comment: вместо `name` указать `tableN.name`

Comment: Не работает. Это первое что пришло в голову) Вываливает ошибку) Насколько я понимаю он воспринимает первый параметр where как столбец в указанной модели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено:

```
$search_string = "hello";
$models = Model::with('table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5')
->whereHas('table3',function($t)use($search_string){
   $t->where('name',$search_string);
})
->get();
```